# How to find the script tag's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find an element relative to script's position? For instance, in the case below I would like `getSelfParent` to return the `$('button')` element

```
<button>
    <script>
        getSelfParent().click(function(){...});
    </script>
</button>
```

`$(this).parent()` did not work.

EDIT:

I want to avoid:

- adding ID's anywhere
- traversing whole tree every time I am looking for the `self` element

Comment: @a'r: this is the way I want to create buttons in my php

Comment: it's very likely that the script will always be inside a certain element so why not just give the element you want to access an ID and access it via $('#id')?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Jakub M: this is the way I want to create buttons in my php.
```

Try to generate HTML|SCRIPT output as:

```
<button>
    <script id='RandomOrUniqueIdValue'>
        var script=document.getElementById('RandomOrUniqueIdValue');
        // var script=$('#RandomOrUniqueIdValue');
    </script>
</button>
```

Comment: so rather than giving the button an id give it to the script (for which id isn't even a valid attribute)?

Comment: @stratton. What if no parent element for script (like button) or it's unknown? And SCRIPT in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535892%28v=VS.85%29.aspx Lookup for ID attribute. in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script check for tag support for global attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's really a way of accessing the parent element of a script tag, as a script is executed in reference to the window object, not the html tag it is in.

generally speaking, rather than copying and pasting the same/similar piece of javascript inside each button element, it would make more sense to just give them a class and access them in a single js function

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
<button>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="myscriptToHide1">
        jQuery('#myscriptToHide1').parents('button').hide();
    </script>
</button>
```